# Redis AOF persistence - rewrite after flushall

Tags: redis

We're trying to determine whether only AOF backups are enough for our redis store. We have a single store that cannot be rebuild from scratch using the original sources, but we can rebuild the last ~month.

Less rebuilding is better in this case, since more recent / accurate data is very valuable.

We're currently only doing AOF backups (because we don't want hickups that RDB backups can cause?) and were wondering if we are safe for an accidental `flushall`.

AOF will write this to the end of the log, so you can undo it. But what if a rewrite takes places after the `flushall`. The new log will be done very fast (because anything before `flushall` is irrelevant.

Am I correct in assuming AOF does not protect us for this edge case and we would also need RDB backups?

Answer (score 1):

AOF persistence cannot protect you from `FLUSHALL`, and RDB persistence cannot do that either.

There're two solutions:

1. You can backup an AOF file to another safe place regularly. So that, even if you run FLUSHALL, you can recover from an older version of AOF file. Although you lose some recent writes, depending on the frequency of your backups.
2. Disable FLUSHALL/FLUSHDB with the `rename` config, so that end user cannot run these commands.

Comment: Isn’t option 1 almost exactly what RDB backups are? Periodic snapshots?